# SQLite after delete trigger

Tags: sqlite

I have a table from which data gets deleted due to unknown reasons. One of the steps we think could help is to write a trigger in db and probably record some values in another table which we might think could be the culprit
so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_log_delete after delete on usvn_users_to_projects BEGIN 
   insert into usvn_audit_delete(emp_id, emp_name, emp_is_adm ,ENTRY_DATE ) select        
   uu.users_id , uu.users_login ,uu. users_is_admin ,datetime('now') from usvn_users  
   uu,usvn_users_to_projects up where old.users_id=uu.users_id;
END;
```

but this pulls up a lot of records in the new table.

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT joins the two tables `uu` and `up`, but does not actually use any join restriction on `up`.
Therefore, you get the cartesian product of the two tables, i.e., each `uu` record that matches the WHERE condition gets duplicated once for each `up` record.

You do not actually read anything from that `up` table (`old.users_id` is a single value that is independent of that `up` table), so you should just drop it:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER audit_log_delete
AFTER DELETE ON usvn_users_to_projects
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usvn_audit_delete(emp_id,
                                  emp_name,
                                  emp_is_adm,
                                  entry_date)
      SELECT users_id,
             users_login,
             users_is_admin,
             datetime('now')
      FROM usvn_users
      WHERE users_id = OLD.users_id;
END;
```

Comment: Actually, even this is giving multiple records. Although what you have suggested makes absolute sense but I am wondering if there is some else that causing this

Comment: If `usvn_users.users_id` is the primary key, you cannot get more than one record per deleted record.